# JS: How to add more than one URL into a Javascript-Code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, function

I use this code in my wordpress functions.php-file to add automatically a nofollow to each link of a specific url:

```
function cdx_handel_external_links() {
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
( function( $ ) {

    $("a[href^=http]").click(function(){
      if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
         $(this).attr({
            target: "_blank"
         });
      }
    })

   //Add Nofollow
   $("a").each(function(){
    if(this.href.indexOf('example-url.com') >0 ){
        $(this).attr({
            rel: "nofollow"
         });
    }
   });

} )( jQuery );
</script>
   <?php
}
add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'cdx_handel_external_links', 999);
```

But how can I add new URLs into that code? (I am a coding noob, sry). Maybe via: 
`indexOf('example-url.com','example-url2.com','example-url3.com')`
? Thank you a lot for your help!

EDIT:

I did it the following way as a totally noob and it works for me:

```
function cdx_handel_external_links() {
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
( function( $ ) {

    $("a[href^=http]").click(function(){
      if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
         $(this).attr({
            target: "_blank"
         });
      }
    })

   //Add Nofollow
   $("a").each(function(){
    if(this.href.indexOf('example-url.com') >0 ){
        $(this).attr({
            rel: "nofollow"
         });
    }
   });

 //Add Nofollow 2.domain
   $("a").each(function(){
    if(this.href.indexOf('example-url2.com') >0 ){
        $(this).attr({
            rel: "nofollow"
         });
    }
   });

 //Add Nofollow 3.domain
   $("a").each(function(){
    if(this.href.indexOf('example-url3.com') >0 ){
        $(this).attr({
            rel: "nofollow"
         });
    }
   });

} )( jQuery );
</script>
   <?php
}
add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'cdx_handel_external_links', 999);
```

Comment: or statement....

Comment: which statement?

Comment: Well should have been "OR Operator" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) :

```js
const urls = ['www.example-url.com', 'www.example-url-1.com', 'www.example-url-2.com'];

$('a').each(function() {
  if ( urls.filter(url => url.includes('example-url.com')).length > 0 ) {
    $(this).attr({
      rel: 'nofollow',
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Not going to work when it is a partial match in the full URL

Comment: some() would be better in my eyes since it will stop on the first hit, but filter would work.

Answer (score 0):

We want to know if the href string contains one of a set of banned substrings.

```
let nonFollow = ['example-url.com','example-url2.com','example-url3.com'];

function isNonFollow(anHref) {
    for (i=0; i < nonFollow.length; i++) {
        let href = nonFollow[i];
        if (anHref.indexOf(href) >0) return true;
    });
    return false;
}

$("a").each(function(){
    if(isNonFollow(this.href)){
        $(this).attr({
            rel: "nofollow"
        });
    }
});
```